# Text to Speech Using Apache Web Server

Tags: audio, php, speech-synthesis

I have Apache Web server installed on my Raspberry Pi. I was wondering If I could use javascript,html, and php to create a webpage where the user types some text into a text field and then that text is sent to the php file. Then I want the php file to execute the espeak command to make the Raspberry speak the text that was entered. Is there any way to do this? I am new to php and don't really understand how this works yet. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: A CGI script could be a better approach if you want it to run commands/scripts on the Pi ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089271/i-never-really-understood-what-is-cgi) may of some help,various [tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html)s are available) Another alternative could a external API (e.g. [this](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=you+could+use+google%27s+text+to+speech)), and have a HTML + javascript page linking to it

Comment: N.B. epseak can be used with Python, as shown [here](http://dodgyville.tumblr.com/post/25814402767/simple-python-espeak-example)